# WSDL not displayed using CXF framework

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I'm developping a **SOAP** web service using **CXF** framework. I did what musts be done, but the problem is that i can't see the **WSDL** when i call it from my navigator.

These are my configurations

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- CXF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**This my config file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    
        <jaxws:endpoint implementor="ma.none.net.ws.TestWebService"
            id="helloWorldService" address="/helloTest"></jaxws:endpoint>
    
    </beans>
```

**This my web Service**

```
    package ma.none.net.ws;
    
    import javax.jws.WebService;
    
    import ma.none.net.iws.ITestWebService;
    
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "ma.none.net.iws.ITestWebService", serviceName = "helloWorldService")
    public class TestWebService implements ITestWebService {
    
        @Override
        public String helloEveryOne(String name) {
            return "Hi every One, including you "+name;
        }
    }
```

**and these are the outputs**

[image]

This is what i get when i ask for my wsdl

[image]

The reponse is **200.OK** and i can see the wsdl but i don't know why i can't get the **wsdl** in my navigator, but i suspect that the problem is related to a missing jar, i don't know.

**Thanks for your suggestions.**

Comment: no, mozila navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the annotation `@WebMethod` on your method `helloEveryOne`

Next, to call the operation `helloEveryOne` of your web service, you can try:

[localhost:8080/net/webservices/helloTest/helloEveryOne?name=wsdl](http://localhost:8080/net/webservices/helloTest/helloEveryOne?name=wsdl)